# redux store out of sync store().getState() with state from redux logger

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, server-side-rendering

I have problem with redux store in SSR react app. Everything working great, initialState creating on server received by window.initialState on client. Problem starting when I whant to get current store by store().getState in my App.js

**createStore.js**

```
const configureStore = preloadedState => {

    const store = createStore(
        rootReducer,
        preloadedState || global.__initialData__,
        applyMiddleware(
            promiseMiddleware(),
            thunk,
            // logger
        )
    );

    if (module.hot) {
        // Enable Webpack hot module replacement for reducers
        module.hot.accept('./reducers', () => {
            const nextRootReducer = require('./reducers/index');
            store.replaceReducer(nextRootReducer);
        });
    }
    return store;
}

export default configureStore;
```

**server.js**

```
const stores = createStore( reducers );
stores.dispatch(setLang( serve_lang )); // 'pl'
global.__initialData__ = stores.getState();
let initialDatas = stores.getState();
const store = configureStore( initialDatas );
...
<html>
<script>window.__initialData__ = ${serialize(initialDatas)}</script>
...
```

**client.js**

```
 const store = configureStore(window.__initialData__);

    hydrate(
      <Provider store={store} key={Math.random()}>
        <BrowserRouter>
          <App />
        </BrowserRouter>
    </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
    );

    if (module.hot) {
      module.hot.accept();
    }
```

and in my App.js I want to get my current store by

```
import store from 'configureStore'l
store().getState();
```

**and I always have initialState** when I do store.getState() in App.js

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> and I always have initialState when I do store.getState() in App.js

You are creating a new store instance. That won't be modified because the rest of your components use another one you have created in `client.js`

```
import store from 'configureStore'l
store().getState(); // this is new store not the one you have passed to Provider
```

What you could do is to pass first store instance to App inside `client.js` using properties.

```
const store = configureStore(window.__initialData__);

hydrate(
  <Provider store={store} key={Math.random()}>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <App store={store}/>
    </BrowserRouter>
</Provider>,
document.getElementById('root')
```

Or access it via context (`Provider` actually put its store to the context so that inner "connected" components could access it). You could read about context here. [Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html).

Comment: I pass the store to App but when I do store().getState() I still have initialState :/

Comment: @krystianj You shouldn't do `store().getState()` your `store` function will return new store on every call. Instead you should use `this.props.store` or `this.context.store`. Also you get store state the very exact time you call `this.props.store.getState()` it might change later. So exact time when you read state matters.

Comment: OK - now `this.props.store.getState()` working but how can i operate with store now on client side  ? Can I use dispatch?

Comment: It is possible to create new store on client side with initialState ? so we can dispatch store on client side and access in whole component in app by store().getState() because now when I use store().getState() I create new store...

Comment: I'm not sure I undestand your question. Whenever ssr server accepts new request it creates new store, passes it to components, somehow populates it, then serializes it to `window.__initialData__` and sends html string back to the client. The client then creates new store using serialized data and pass it down to components. So everything you put in  store on the server before serializing will be avalialble on the client. If you add something after serialization client won't see it. If your client changes something server wont see it (process is one directional).

Comment: Thank you Yury for your advice. I create higher order component and I think this will resolve my problem...